# Why concatenate and sort methods behave weirdly? 2 Esentially same ways dont work in same way

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on FCC challenges, learning JS. Here is the [link](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/certifications/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/functional-programming/return-a-sorted-array-without-changing-the-original-array/) of challenge that cofuses me.

I kinda solved it, but one code that should work, while other does not, and I would assume they are essentially the same things.

This is a code that works:

```
var globalArray = [5, 6, 3, 2, 9];
function nonMutatingSort(arr) {
  // Add your code below this line
  return [].concat(arr).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  // Add your code above this line
}
nonMutatingSort(globalArray);
```

And this code does not work

```
var globalArray = [5, 6, 3, 2, 9];
function nonMutatingSort(arr) {
  // Add your code below this line
  let newArr = [];
  newArr.concat(arr);
  return newArr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
  // Add your code above this line
}
nonMutatingSort(globalArray);
```

My question is essentially why?
Both codes concatenate old array to new one, and both functions should return sorted array.

However in first function concatenation fails... it returns only empty arr. 
Why? I am so confused. It works outside of the function, however not in function.

Comment: I think that once you put `{}` you must use a `return` statement. Try in the second one: `{ return a-b }`

Comment: I was typing code istead of copypasting it, but thank you. Edited.

Comment: please upvote if it was helpful .Thanks

Comment: `.slice()` is usually used to shallow copy array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` does not mutate any existing array (either the array the function is called on, or the array(s) in the parameter list). When you call `concat`, you return a *new* array. So, the standalone statement

```
newArr.concat(arr);
```

does not do anything - you concatenated `newArr` with `arr`, creating a new combined array, but that combined array is not assigned to anything; it gets evaluated and then discarded.

```js
const arr1 = ['a'];
const arr2 = ['b'];

// Does not do anything by itself:
arr1.concat(arr2);

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Assign the result to `newArr` instead:

```
newArr = newArr.concat(arr);
```

```js
var globalArray = [5, 6, 3, 2, 9];
function nonMutatingSort(arr) {
  // Add your code below this line
  let newArr = [];
  newArr = newArr.concat(arr);
  return newArr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
  // Add your code above this line
}
console.log(nonMutatingSort(globalArray));
// Original array is not mutated:
console.log(globalArray);
```

Or, avoid the initial declaration of `newArr` entirely, and use your original code (which I'd prefer). Actually, to be even more terse, you might just `slice` the original array, rather than explicitly creating an empty one:

```js
var globalArray = [5, 6, 3, 2, 9];
const nonMutatingSort = arr => arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(nonMutatingSort(globalArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

concat method return a new array so you need to save in same variable or in another variable. In your case :

```
var globalArray = [5, 6, 3, 2, 9];
function nonMutatingSort(arr) {
  // Add your code below this line
  let newArr = [];
  newArr = newArr.concat(arr); //here it will return new new which you need to save
  return newArr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
  // Add your code above this line
}
nonMutatingSort(globalArray);
```